# Неверное отображение цвета текстуры

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

На UI image вывожу импортированный из файла спрайт. Все цвета становятся немного выцветшими по сравнению с изначальными цветами текстуры. Пробовал изменять настройки импорта, менял Color Space в Project Settings, но ничего не помогло. Как можно добиться того, чтобы в игре отображались точно такие же цвета, как и в изначальной текстуре?

Изначальная картинка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева картинка, которая отображается в юнити, а справа изначальная текстура.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прикрепи текстуру

Comment: ты показал картинку в окне "игра", так что проблема может быть в свете на сцене. Прикрепи скриншот картинки из ресурсов юнити

Comment: Но ведь это UI картинка. Как может свет на нее влиять? К тому же она неправильно отображается еще на этапе импорта

Comment: Вот что получилось я изменил adobe RGB на gimp sRGB и все стало лучше. Попробуй экспортировать из фотошопа с другими настройками, или вообще не экспортируй, юнити должен уметь читать фотошоповские файлы

Comment: @ValeraKvip Спасибо! Смена цветового пространства в фотошопе помогла. Сменил с Adobe RGB на sRGB IEC61966-2.1 (цветовое пространство моего монитора).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы цвета показывались правильно необходимо в фотошопе назначить картинке цветовое пространство sRGB IEC61966-2.1 (в моем случае). Для этого нажать Редактирование -> Преобразовать в профиль...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего цвета начнут отображаться правильно.