# Unity меняет цвет некоторых частей картинки

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

В Unity картинка меняет цвет части пикселей

**Так выглядит изначально до импорта:**

[image: Так выглядит изначально до импорта]

**А вот после импорта в Unity:**

[image: А вот после импорта в Unity]

Comment: посмотри это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1169034/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b#comment2030258_1169034

Comment: Настройка спрайта для пиксельарта `Filter Mode: Point (no filter)`.

Comment: @Valera Kvip, Yaroslav исправилось изменением Compression на None

Comment: напиши в ответ. Можно со скрином